# Why does not Warble include .class files in war file?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

when I warble my project, it doesn't include .class files to war file.

My config/warble.rb file is like that:

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
  config.features = %w(compiled executable)
  config.dirs << "bin"
  config.dirs << "public"
  config.includes = FileList["Rakefile"]
  config.executable = ["rake", "bin/rake"]
end
```

It was compiled yesterday but not compile and include for now. Also when I run warble compiled, it just rm .class files.

Comment: I was using warble gem '1.4.0' and updated to '1.4.2' it solved my problem.

Comment: ... you should answer your question than and mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using warble gem '1.4.0' and updated to '1.4.2' it solved my problem.